# Save custom bitmap into UniversalImage Loader

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage, universal-image-loader

Im using Universal Image Loader and works well in my app, however i need get the app icons and shorcuts bitmaps, And As far that i know can't get this using UIL, so i use package manager or other resource to load the bitmaps, so my problem is if ican use any option to "push" into UIL the bitmap and then "pull" this bitmap if its available i can use

```
MemoryCacheUtil.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

Whith this code i can get the cached bitmap but its possible "save" the image using UIL?